# Between multiple graph can I change the data series all at once when hover on one graphs using Blazor

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, maui-blazor

how can I do Parameter Linkage in a blazor with multiple graph? Does anyone have a sample?
Literately I want to achieve this: https://towardsdatascience.com/dynamic-charts-make-your-data-move-19e540a06bd3 using blazor

Comment: Here are some discussions about [Charts and Graphs in .NET MAUI](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/4468).